# Changing app namespace in a cordova app for android platform

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I already had an app on play store. I want to update my app changing it with a cordova app. My namespace and version number is different and when I tried to upload the new apk, it warns me for namespace and version number. What should I do?

Comment: i think you cannot do that due to google play restrictions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace of your app should not change, the version number should become higher.
Both you can set in the `config.xml` of your codova project (in case of phonegap build etc) or change them in the Android Manifest and then refactor your src/ folders to follow that same package name.

Comment: But play console warns me like:"Your APK needs to have the package name [old namespace]". It's different than my new cordova app's.

Comment: Yes, because it needs to be the same, the package name is the unique identifier of your app.  Just change the android:package attribute in your manifest, and then refactor your src/ folders to follow that same package name.